# RestfulAPI URL with multiple slashes responds normally

Tags: c#, url

This is a C# question that *might* be related to Web, so, experts will advise.

I have a RestAPI to which I send requests (PUT, GET mainly). The base URL is, let's say, `http://192.168.126.121:6677/base/rest/ini"`.

After this, for operation XYZ, I have to call for example 
`http://192.168.126.121:6677/base/rest/ini/customer/acc/list`

I noticed that my consoleapp runs normally even if I call
`http://192.168.126.121:6677/base/rest/ini/customer/acc//////list`

(Notice the `acc//////list` part).

My question is dual:

1. C# how can I forbid multiple `/` in my task and concatenate all the `/` into one?
   i.e. I get a URI from like `http://192.168.126.121:6677/base/rest/ini/customer/acc//////list` and I want to end up with `http://192.168.126.121:6677/base/rest/ini/customer/acc/list`
2. for any experts in the field: is it normal that I get normal responses from the
   `http://192.168.126.121:6677/base/rest/ini/customer/acc//////list` url?

Thank you very much

Comment: Not familiar with this but [RewriteOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.rewrite.rewriteoptions?view=aspnetcore-3.1) could help you to rewrite the url and redirect to the new one.
[URL Rewriting Middleware in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: Besides wanting clean URLs and clear expectations, why do you want to forbid this?

Comment: @A Friend I am not sure if this is valid, hence I want to forbid it. I just read on the Rewrite option, thing is, I don't have access to the web server and I just found out that this works (the multiple slashes I mean) and I want to make a recommendation to forbid this, and at the same time make sure I am calling the proper URL. For the later (b) I found a solution using Uri object in C#. So concerning (a) I am still quite suspicious that this is to be allowed...